# How can i move multiple files to folder with same name

Tags: command-line, bash, mv

I have multiple files like this:

```
round3-bcF_01_bcR_01.R1.fastq
round3-bcF_01_bcR_01.R2.fastq
round4-bcF_01_bcR_01.R1.fastq
round4-bcF_01_bcR_01.R2.fastq
round3-bcF_01_bcR_02.R1.fastq
round3-bcF_01_bcR_02.R2.fastq
round4-bcF_01_bcR_02.R1.fastq
round4-bcF_01_bcR_02.R2.fastq
```

and goes on until this form:

```
round3-bcF_12_bcR_08.R1.fastq
round3-bcF_12_bcR_08.R2.fastq
```

Also, I have different folders like these ones:

```
bcF_01_bcR_01
bcF_01_bcR_02
bcF_01_bcR_03
```

etc... until

```
bcF_12_bcR_08
```

I'm moving the files with this line:

```
mv *-bcF_01_bcR_01* bcF_01_bcR_01
```

Therefore, 4 files should be left in each folder, but its taking me forever because I have to run 96 times the code ( I have more replicas so I have more than 96 folders).

All I want is to move files with this part of the name "bcF_01_bcR_01" to folders of the same name. Im new with bash so any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Welcome!  Could you explain a bit which files correspond to which folder?

Comment: Hi schrodigerscatcuriosity, these files  : round3-bcF_01_bcR_01.R1.fastq, round3-bcF_01_bcR_01.R2.fastq, round4-bcF_01_bcR_01.R1.fastq and round4-bcF_01_bcR_01.R2.fastq correspond to the folder  bcF_01_bcR_01. I have a total of 96 folders which i created with this code : mkdir bcF_{1..12}_bcR_{1..8}

Comment: I'm sorry cuz my comments are disorganized but it's my first post and I don't know how to use the options well or how to edit the comments :(

Comment: you can zero pad sequence expansion `{01..08}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, probably the most simple way is to use the builtin `for` loop in a way as this:

```bsh
for i in {01..08}; do echo mv *-bcF_01_bcR_${i}* bcF_01_bcR_${i}/; done
```

- remove the `echo` command in order to do the actual file-system changes.

Answer (score 2):

Using rename to move files:

```
$ rename -n 's/.*(bcF_[0-9]+_bcR_[0-9]+).*/$1\/$&/' *.fastq
```

<sup>Remove -n when you feel ready to move your files.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

`mmv` (from the package of the same name) is useful for cases like this:

```
$ mmv -n '*-bcF_01_bcR_*.*' 'bcF_01_bcR_#2/'
round3-bcF_01_bcR_01.R1.fastq -> bcF_01_bcR_01/round3-bcF_01_bcR_01.R1.fastq
round3-bcF_01_bcR_01.R2.fastq -> bcF_01_bcR_01/round3-bcF_01_bcR_01.R2.fastq
round3-bcF_01_bcR_02.R1.fastq -> bcF_01_bcR_02/round3-bcF_01_bcR_02.R1.fastq
round3-bcF_01_bcR_02.R2.fastq -> bcF_01_bcR_02/round3-bcF_01_bcR_02.R2.fastq
round4-bcF_01_bcR_01.R1.fastq -> bcF_01_bcR_01/round4-bcF_01_bcR_01.R1.fastq
round4-bcF_01_bcR_01.R2.fastq -> bcF_01_bcR_01/round4-bcF_01_bcR_01.R2.fastq
round4-bcF_01_bcR_02.R1.fastq -> bcF_01_bcR_02/round4-bcF_01_bcR_02.R1.fastq
round4-bcF_01_bcR_02.R2.fastq -> bcF_01_bcR_02/round4-bcF_01_bcR_02.R2.fastq
```

Here, `#2` refers to the second wildcard match in the expression `*-bcF_01_bcR_*.*` - you can easily extend it to do multiple replacements in a single shot e.g.

```
mmv -n '*-bcF_*_bcR_*.*' 'bcF_#2_bcR_#3/'
```

Remove the `-n` to actually make the moves. If you use `zsh`, it has a loadable equivalent `zmv`.